# What does the << operator definite usages in grails?

Tags: java, grails, groovy, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

I am starting work with grails.
I am quite confused in grails about using this << (bitwise left shift) operator.

I think it is use for assigning some value/object like
assignedTo << assignedValue

`def outputBook = { output << Book.read(1) }`

Is this the definite concept or not ?

Comment: is the output hold the Book.read(1) value and return it or something else.Can anyone help about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically this is a Groovy and not Grails operator, and it's the additive operand. I seem to recall it delegates to the `append` method of the left hand. So for a collection it would add the element to the collection.

For example:

```
def things = ['one', 'two']
assert things.size() == 2
things << 'three'
assert things.size() == 3
```

The left shift << operator in Java is only used for bitwise operations. However, Groovy overrides this by delegating all operands to methods. This allows you implement your own. Take for instance the following use of plus:

```
class Baby {
  String name
  String toString(){"Baby: ${name}"}
}
class Person {
  String name
  def plus(Person o) {
    return new Baby(name: "${this.name} - ${o.name}")
  }
​}

def person1 = new Person(name: "Person 1")
def person2 = new Person(name: "Person 2")
assert "Baby: Person 1 - Person 2" == (person1 + person2)
​
```

Pretty Groovy eh?

Comment: thanks for reply.Can you give some examples with brief.

Comment: As Joshua Moore said, this is really an example of "operator overloading" within Groovy.  Probably the most used example is with collection to over the add() method, but if you look at some of the Grails scripts, they also use this overloading as well.